# Functions second argument being passed as a conditional?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, if-statement

The functions task is to set and clear help messages in the form field using built in css classes. My question is why do I need to validate the helpText argument within the function to be non equative to null? The argument is linked by the id it shares with the span tag so why is validation necessary?

```
<input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" size="12" onblur="validateNonEmpty"(this, document.getElementById('phone_help'))" />

<span id="phone_help" class="help"></span>

function validateNonEmpty(inputField, helpText) {

// See if the input value contains any text

if (inputField.value.length == 0) {

// The data is invalid, so set the help message

if (helpText != null)

    helpText.innerHTML = "Please enter a value.";

return false;

}

else {

    // The data is OK, so clear the help message

    if (helpText != null)

        helpText.innerHTML = "";

    return true;    
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a function, you're creating a piece of code that may be executed multiple times in a variety of contexts. In JavaScript, when calling a function, it's not guaranteed that the necessary arguments were provided, nor is it guaranteed that they are of the correct type. The non-strict comparison with `null` in your code is making sure that the `helpText` argument was provided when the function was called. **This is just a safety mechanism to help prevent developer error.**

In large scale applications written by teams of people, you're likely to see these kinds of checks performed all the time. Writing safe code means considering all the ways it may fail, which means considering the very likely possibility that someone else using your code may not use it correctly. Often, that "someone else" is you from the future, looking in bewilderment at the nonsense you wrote last week.

Comment: This is the most important part of the answer! 
`Often, that "someone else" is you from the future, looking in bewilderment at the nonsense you wrote last week.`